# How does getChildren() access the outer class object?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a outer class that extends Pane. Within it, is a handler class that implements EventHandler. In that handler class, the handle() method can call the getChildren() method without referencing any objects? Why/how can it do that? How does it know who's children is it getting? Thanks :)

```
private class Handler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        getChildren().clear();
    }
```

Comment: From the duplicate, just so you don't have to search, the answer is _Each instance of the inner class is enclosed by a single instance of the outer class. Again, all the access privileges of static nested classes apply to inner classes. But since they already have an instance of the outer class available, they can automatically access instance variables and methods of the outer class._

Comment: Ohh okay. So if I'm understanding this correctly: the inner class has access to the children of the outer Pane class. So when you call getChildren() without any references to any object, it will get the children of the outer class? Thanks

Comment: Of the corresponding enclosing class _instance_, yes.